# What will be the typical components in the audio spectrum of a glass tumbler?

Tags: acoustics

If we strike a glass tumbler with a metal bar and analyse its audio spectrum, what are the expected components? Can we assure that the most intense frequency will be the resonant frequency and others being the higher order harmonics?

Comment: There is no reason to expect the modes to be harmonics.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the object is to complex to have just 1 resonant frequency, the top edge would be the part that will oscillate easier and you could get that tone as the principal frequency.

But it depends where you hit it, the tone that you will get.

Take a much simpler shape, a piece of wood, 2 inches long 1 inch wide and 5 inches deep.

Depending where you hit it the frequency that you are going to get, for start you have 3 different longitudinal waves frequency that you are going to get, and then in the transversal way you are going to have others natural frequencies, again depending where you hit it.